# Покрыть тестом значение в методе

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Есть класс в котором есть метод.
В методе инициализируется переменная String, ей присваивается ссылка.

```
String baseLkUrlStripped = StringUtils.stripEnd(getBaseLkUrl(),"/");
```

`getBaseLkUrl()` берет ссылку из property.

Мне важно протестировать изменение этой переменной, чтобы если другой человек поменяет значение в property то `baseLkUrlStripped` измениться.

Можете подсказать логику как это покрыть тестом? Используется mockito, junit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так

```
when(getBaseLkUrl()).thenReturn("/");
String baseLkUrlStripped = StringUtils.stripEnd(getBaseLkUrl(),"/");
assertEquals("", baseLkUrlStripped);
```